# inserting trigger on same table after insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS_1
(
NAME VARCHAR2(50)NOT NULL,
DIV VARCHAR2(5) CHECK (DIV IN ('E','F','G')),
MARKS NUMBER CHECK (MARKS <= 600),
GRADE VARCHAR2(5) CHECK (GRADE IN ('A','B','C'))
)
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MARKS 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON STUDENTS_1
FOR EACH ROW 


BEGIN

IF (:NEW.MARKS>500)THEN 
INSERT INTO STUDENTS_1(MARKS,GRADE)VALUES(:NEW.MARKS,'A');

ELSIF (:NEW.MARKS>400 AND:NEW.MARKS<500) THEN 
INSERT INTO STUDENTS_1(MARKS,GRADE)VALUES(:NEW.MARKS,'B');

ELSE (:NEW.MARKS <400 )
INSERT INTO STUDENTS_1(MARKS,GRADE)VALUES(:NEW.MARKS,'C');


END IF ;
END;/
```

I would insert marks into this table and i want trigger to trigger grade accordingly into the same table with respect to what marks i'm entering and  i'm getting `not enough values error` when i'm doing this 
So i wanted to know that what i'm doing is it possible or there's another way ??

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with this approach.  First of all, if you could insert into `students_1` in an insert trigger on `students_1`, you'd create an infinite loop. You'd do an insert, firing the trigger, which would do an insert, which would fire the trigger, which would do an insert, which would fire the trigger...  Second, you presumably want to set the `grade` value for the current row, not create a new row.  The `grade` presumably relates to the `mark` of the row you are in the process of inserting.

You probably just want to update the `grade` in the `:new` pseudorecord

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  case when :new.marks < 400
       then :new.grade := 'C';
       when :new.marks between 400 and 500
       then :new.grade := 'B';
       when :new.marks > 500
       then :new.grade := 'A';
   end case;
END;
```

If this is a real problem rather than a homework assignment that requires a trigger, you probably want a virtual column for `grade` that includes the calculation rather than writing a trigger to maintain a computed column.

Comment: "If this is a real problem rather than a homework assignment" - I sure hope that the questions we see relating to classes, grades, etc are real-world problems, because if they are I think we can reasonably conclude that educational institutions are employing a lot of developers who ask a lot of beginner-level questions and thus may be delivering less-than-stellar applications to their employers. This leads me to think that there is a HUGE market opportunity for competently designed and written class/student/grade software! 'Scuse me - I gotta go... :-)